# JTable , update the table whenever click on a button

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

I am currently trying to learn JTable with MySQL. I've set my database into JTable and added it into my GUI with using scroll pane.

My question is, how can I make a function to renew my database or do a search operation (both are the same thing so..) whenever I click on my button.

Here is my code (I am reading the database informations into my .ini file)

```
final Vector columnNames = new Vector();
        final Vector data = new Vector();

        try
        {
            //  Connect to an Access Database



            driver = IniFonksiyon.iniSVNOkut(driver, "databaseBilgileri", "driver");//"com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
            url = IniFonksiyon.iniOkut(url, "databaseBilgileri", "url");//"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
            userid = IniFonksiyon.iniOkut(userid, "databaseBilgileri", "kullanici");
            password = IniFonksiyon.iniOkut(password, "databaseBilgileri", "sifre");
            dbName = IniFonksiyon.iniOkut(dbName, "databaseBilgileri", "dbIsmi");

            Class.forName( driver );
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection( url+dbName , userid, password );

            //  Read data from a table

            String sql = "select * from profildb.tbl_detailed";
            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( sql );

            ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
            int columns = md.getColumnCount();

            //  Get column names

            for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
            {
                columnNames.addElement( md.getColumnName(i) );
            }

            //  Get row data

            while (rs.next())
            {
                Vector row = new Vector(columns);

                for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
                {
                    row.addElement( rs.getObject(i) );
                }

                data.addElement( row );
            }

            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            connection.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println( e );
        }

        //  Create table with database data

        final JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames)
        {
            /**
             * 
             */
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            public Class getColumnClass(int column)
            {
                for (int row = 0; row < getRowCount(); row++)
                {
                    Object o = getValueAt(row, column);

                    if (o != null)
                    {
                        return o.getClass();
                    }
                }

                return Object.class;
            }
        };
```

This is the code that handles creating the table, but its directly connected with my main GUI function, so How can I refresh/do another operation like search function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easier to use a table model. See a related [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data). You can use [DefaultTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html) or your own implementation of `TableModel`. 
Extension of `AbstractTableModel` usually is a most common approach if `DefaultTableModel` does not satisfy your needs.

For better performance and responsiveness of Swing application the execution of long running tasks should not happen on [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). So, it is best to access database from a thread other than EDT.

[SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) can be used for such purpose. Get data from database in `SwingWorker.doInBackground()`. Then, either build or update your model in `SwingWorker.done()`.

There are many variations of such implementation. These are specific to your application's nature and requirements. For instance you can use SwingWorker's `publish()/process()` tandem to process data in chunks. You may choose to incorporate database access logic into your model or create commands that extend `SwingWorker`.

Comment: Hey, Thank you for the answer.I understand, so could I directly implement DefaultTableModel to my code or do I have to change my Table's code?

Comment: @Yesilmen , Either DefaultTableModel or your own implementation of TableModel. Let the model manage the actual data, and the table be responsible for its presentation.